# criação de menu no html5 e css3

Tags: html5, css3

Eu criei um menu com HTML5 e CSS3, até ai tudo bem, deixei ele bem no canto superior da tela e tudo certinho, só que quando abro o mesmo arquivo em outra tela o menu não está mais formatado no canto certinho como eu tinha deixado.

Alguém tem alguma dica ou algo que eu estou deixando de fazer?

```css
nav#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 450px
}
nav#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: -1px
}
nav#menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header1">
  <hgroup>
    <h1>Milky Way</h1>
    <h2>Solar System</h2>
  </hgroup>

  <img id="icone" src="_images/solarsystems01.png" alt="this images is about solar systems" title="solar system" width="250" height="50" align="right"/>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li onmouseover="mudaFoto('_images/Mercurio.png')" onmouseout="mudaFoto('_images/solarsystems01.png')"><a href="sun.html">Sun</a></li>
      <li>Mercury</li>
      <li>Venus</li>
      <li>Earth</li>
      <li>Mars</li>
      <li>Jupter</li>
      <li>Saturn</li>
      <li>Uranus</li>
      <li>Neptune</li>
      <li>Pluto</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: tente colocar exemplo do seu código para ficar verificavel de uma lida em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e também [Crie um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Manda o Código, posso ajudar a resolver!

Comment: nav#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 450px
}

Comment: Coloca o HTML tb. E usa o botão {} do editor pra formatar o código

Comment: Quando você dize que abre o arquivo em outra tela, ao que exatamente você se refere?

Comment: coloquei os codigos, e desculpa é a minha primeira pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Cara não sei se entendi muito bem, mas em fim. Interpretei como se você quisesse deixar seu menu no canto superior direito da tela.

Caso esse seja o problema a solução pode ser bem simples.

No seu seletor `nav#menu ul`

```
nav#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 450px
}
```

Você está colocando o valor negativo no seu top sendo que não tem necessidade, basta você adicionar o `margin: 0;` e `top: 0;` para ele ficar totalmente no topo da sua tela.

Agora para deixar seu menu no canto direito você deve adicionar a propriedade right: 0; pois essa propriedade vai deixar seu menu 0 pixels na direita, ou seja, colado no lado direito da tela.

Resumindo, tente deixar seu código para esse seletor dessa forma:

```
nav#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Dessa forma seu menu deve funcionar em outras telas conforme o esperado.
Espero que a resposta seja útil.

Comment: deu certo man obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz que ajudou cara.